# Restrict select statement to view records

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 tables 
Gallery
id=primary key
photo
related
Categories
id=primary key
title=varchar data type
Section
id=primary key
Related=Foreign key for categories id table
Each gallery have a category and each category have many sections.
when user clicks on category title I want to load only sections which is related to categories table.

This is the main part and working fine

```
<div class="image-set">
<?php
$selectgallery=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM gallery  where relation='".$_REQUEST['gall']."' && project='A");
while($resultgallery=$querygallery->fetch_assoc()) {
?>
 <a class="example-image-link" href="images/fcomail/gallery/<?php echo $resultgallery['name']; ?>" rel="lightbox[roadtrip]" ><img class="example-image" src="images/fcomail/gallery/<?php echo $resultgallery['name']; ?>" width="110" height="100"></a>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
```

I have a side bar which will show the sections related  to category

```
<div class="page-dta-right" 
               <table class="slide-tb">
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" >
                    <p class="slide-title">
                  <strong>CATEGORIES</strong></p>               </td>
                </tr> <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"  valign="top" height="1px" >
                  <hr/></td>
                </tr>
               <?php 
               $section_query=$connection->query("SELECT * FROM gallery_section where? ---Here is the problem---- ");
               while($res123=$section_query->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                <tr>
                  <td width="81%"><p class="slide-txt-body">  
                <a href="gall2.php?gall=<?php echo $res123['id']; ?>"><?php echo $res123['title']; ?> </a> </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" align="center"  valign="top" height="1px" >
                  <hr/></td>
                </tr><?php } ?>
              </table></div>
```

Any advise on how to restract select statement which is related to category.

Comment: What are the fields in the `gallery_section` table?

Comment: Yes it is a table name